# Error when deploying solution webparts - Cant figure out why its failing

Tags: web-part, solution-deployment

I'm trying to deploy [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/751882/Event-Calendar-Listing-Web-Part-SharePoint) webpart

I can get it to work on Dev with no issues. But I have problem when deploying it to production.

1. First of all I can't get to see anything in the site collection feature
2. When I go to the webpart gallery and click on it Ii get error

   > An error occurred when previewing the Web Part.**

When I looked at my logs I can see

```
06/29/2015 17:14:44.93  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request (GET:http://XXX/_layouts/15/WPPrevw.aspx?ID=81)    7e05159d-8e24-10ae-118e-e20a8660b17a    
06/29/2015 17:14:44.93  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   Request Management  ai2q3   High    Reached maximum number of failed machines based on ping results for this routing group  7e05159d-8e24-10ae-118e-e20a8660b17a    
06/29/2015 17:14:44.93  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   Request Management  ai2q4   Medium  Unavailable machines based on ping results: servername  7e05159d-8e24-10ae-118e-e20a8660b17a    
06/29/2015 17:14:44.93  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   Request Management  adc7u   Medium  Mapping URI from 'http://XXX:80/_layouts/15/WPPrevw.aspx?ID=81' to 'http://XXXX/_layouts/15/WPPrevw.aspx?ID=81' 7e05159d-8e24-10ae-118e-e20a8660b17a    
06/29/2015 17:14:45.01  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   Request Management  aeboc   High    [Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 06/29/2015 17:14:44.93, Original Level: Verbose] No data was found on the incoming client request  7e05159d-8e24-10ae-118e-e20a8660b17a    
06/29/2015 17:14:45.01  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   Request Management  aht6j   High    [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] Proxy response duration: WFE '{0}', RM '{1}'   7e05159d-8e24-10ae-118e-e20a8660b17a    
06/29/2015 17:14:45.01  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   General adyrv   High    Cannot find site lookup info for request Uri http://XXX/.   7e05159d-8e24-10ae-118e-e20a8660b17a    
06/29/2015 17:14:45.01  w3wp.exe (0x5E84)   0x3CE8  SharePoint Foundation   Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://XXX/_layouts/15/WPPrevw.aspx?
```

If anyone has gone through something similar I would appreciate some feedback.

One more thing though is on the dev my site URL is e.g `http://servername:portnumber`
and prod is using host header e.g `http://abc.yoga.com`

This is the command I use to deploy it to a specific web app.

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath  "D:\Somepaths\QuestechSystems.SharePoint.EventCalendarList.wsp"

Install-SPSolution –Identity questechsystems.sharepoint.eventcalendarlist.wsp –WebApplication "http://test.com" –GACDeployment -Force
```

Comment: were you able to successfully install the solution? were there any errors!

Comment: No errors at all.Thanks Taran .
That is the only error i can see on the log

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact commands you wrote. Thanks

Comment: I know you must have done all this but I am just trying to help. 1. Please make sure that you are in the site collection feature section. i.e.  "http://site/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site"  2. Please go to "http://CentralAdmin/_admin/Solutions.aspx" and check if the solution is properly deployed or not. I am trying to replicate the scenario.

Comment: It was properly deployed.
For some reason it appears to be working now :: Thanks for your comments